# 'NoneType' object is not for beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scraping. However due to this error not able to go ahead. I would be great if anyone can help me with this.

This is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findALL("div",{"class":"item-branding"})
```

BELOW IS THE ERROR

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
13
14
---> 15 containers = page_soup.findALL("div",{"class":"item-branding"})
16 length(containers)
17

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: try with `find_all` instead of `findALL`...!

Comment: what is the progress ??

Answer (score 1):

it is `page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-branding"})` . Not `page_soup.findALL("div",{"class":"item-branding"})` (Note the small 'l')